# VBA copy filtered table within loop to new sheets

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy

I have a table, with a lot of columns. I'd like to filter the table one after the other by a few values appearing in one specific column. Once the table is filtered (for one value), I'd like to copy the result to a new sheet and go on with the second value. (Actually I'd like to copy it to a new workbook and save it, but that's the next step.)

Here's my code:

```
'Start Loop
Public Sub LP()


    Dim years As Variant
    Dim number As Variant

    'Array for loop
    years = Array("2013", "20131", "20132")
    For Each number In years

        ' filter definition (filter by number)
        Dim i As Integer, rngData As Range
        Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("ColumnXY", Range("A1:BM1"), 0)
        rngData.AutoFilter field:=i, Criteria1:=number


        'Copy filtered data to new sheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim WS As Worksheet
        For Each row In Range("Tabelle1[#All]").Rows
            If row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = row
                Set rng = Union(row, rng)
            End If
        Next row

        Set WS = Sheets.Add
        rng.copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")

        'Delete specific columns in the new sheet
        WS.Range("A:AD,AP:AQ,AS:BE,BG:BH,BJ:BK").EntireColumn.Delete

        'Autofit Column
        Columns("A:N").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        'Tabelle1=1 active table
        Sheets("Tabelle1").Select

        'Remove filter and show all data
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        End If

    'go on with next number
    Next number
End Sub
```

3 Sheets will be generated after running the script and the first sheet is fine (all datas of 2013). The second sheet contains unfortunally all rows from the frist two numbers (2013 and 20131) and the third sheet contains the data from all numbers. I aim to get a sheet for the data for one number indivudally and I can't see, what's wrong ...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: "3 Sheets will be generated after running the script and the first sheet is fine (all datas of 2013). The second sheet contains unfortunally all rows from the frist two numbers (2013 and 20131) and the third sheet contains the data from all numbers. I aim to get a sheet for the data for one number indivudally and I can't see, what's wrong ..."

Comment: Yes, I read that, what IS happening with your code?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. The code is ok so far, the only problem is that all datas are copied together per number. I guess "numbers" will not be set right in the loop or the filter will not be removed before starting the loop again. I've tested it seperatly and it seemed fine to me ..